# mysql - can I set VARCHAR default value as NULL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1067

In mysql, i tried changing an existing table like this:

```
  ALTER TABLE  `etexts` CHANGE  `etext`  `etext` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

I got the response:

```
  #1067 - Invalid default value for 'etext'
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's contradictive... `NOT NULL`, but make it default `NULL`...
Remove `DEFAULT NULL` and change `NOT NULL` to `NULL`:

```
ALTER TABLE  `etexts` CHANGE  `etext`  `etext` VARCHAR( 100 ) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks - strangely enough, thats what phpmyadmin generated for me!! (what i had pasted above in my question)

Comment: phpMyAdmin is not always right. You might want to fill in a bug if it's not already reported.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a NOT NULL column defaulting to NULL.

If you want it to be NULLable then

```
... COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NULL
```

NULLABLE columns will default to NULL automagically if no value is provided for the column